# Minor spello/typo on the "Complex Queries" documentation page

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

The documentation page

> [***Complex Queries***](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/min-max)

has a minor typo or spello:

> The `?filter=total` build-in filter is provided for just this purpose.

Should instead be:

> The `?filter=total` built-in filter is provided for just this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next build will fix this, thanks for reporting it.

Comment: BTW, in case you haven't seem them already, there are some more typos:  http://stackapps.com/q/6899/26088 and http://stackapps.com/q/6893/26088. (if you have seen them, sorry for pinging you again! :)