# Typos on api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

Under the Authentication section on https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib, there are a few typos (emphasis mine):

> scope (optional) – an array of scopes to request during authentication, valid scopes are in the authentication **documentaiton**.

`documentaiton` => `documentation`

> If networkUsers was not passed to SE.authenticate networkUsers will **not bet set**, if set it is an array of network_user objects.

`not bet set` => `not be set`

---

Under the Errors section:

> Note that **the user reject** an application is conceptually an error.

`the user reject` => `the user rejecting`

---

Under the Unregistered Users section:

> We want to provide this data, but we also want to be able to shut down **scrappers** who aren't following our attribution terms

`scrappers` => `scrapers`

---

Also, this isn't a typo, but I think this could be rephrased:

> Once you have authenticated a user once

the duplicate `once` doesn't sound right!

As [@JF suggests](https://stackapps.com/questions/6893/typos-on-api-stackexchange-com-docs-js-lib?noredirect=1#comment14890_6893), it could be:

> After you have authenticated a user once

Comment: Maybe the last one should be “After you have authenticated the user once.”

Comment: @JF sounds good! edited question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed, thanks to [ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, for bringing it to my attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310650/spelling-mistake-in-stack-exchange-inc-api-terms-of-use-page/310680?noredirect=1#comment1015031_310680), rolling out in next API build.