# Few typos in the documentation pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/vectors

> When passing a vector, **sepeate** each id with a semicolon. For example, /users/1;2;3;4;5?site=somesite would fetch users with ids 1 through 5 on somesite.

sepeate => sep**ar**ate

---

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/min-max

> Another handy trick is to only request the total field when all you care about is the **quanity** of items meeting some criteria, such as when calculating statistics. The `?filter=total` built-in filter is provided for just this purpose.

quanity => quan**t**ity

---

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper

> The `error_*` fields, while technically **elligible** for filtering, will not actually be excluded in an error case. This is by design.

el**l**igible => eligible

---

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging

> `total` is also a useful property when displaying paging controls. In this case applications would want to include both `items` and `total` on a filter rather than making two **seperate** requests.

seperate => sep**a**rate

---

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression

> While effectively all browsers will always request compressed content, many (if not all) of the applications using our API will be on **decidely** less mature HTTP stacks. The likelihood of many applications not opting into compression, and being materially worse for it, is unacceptable.

decidely => decide**d**ly

---

Few other words, not sure they are typos:

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper

> When building filters, this common wrapper object has no name. Refer to it with a leading ., so the items field would be **refered** to via .items.

refered => refer**r**ed

---

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters

> The motivation for filters are several fold. Filters allow applications to reduce API responses to just the fields they are concerned with, saving bandwidth. With the list of fields an application is actually concerned with, the API can avoid **unneccessary** queries thereby decreasing response time ...

unnec**c**essary => unnecessary

---

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids

> {ids} can contain up to 100 semicolon delimited ids, to find ids **programatically** look for user_id on user or shallow_user objects.

programatically => program**m**atically

Comment: lol the docs really do have loads of typos! :P and yeah, those other words are typos it seems.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ : Even I looked only this [Documentation page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and the links form that pages only _(not on side bar links)_. If you cross-check on other pages, it will be more.

Comment: Looks like someone fixed `programatically => programmatically` on [users-by-ids](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids), but the rest of these are still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixes for this were just pushed in the latest build. Thanks for reporting it.